# Import modules from files or directories does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got a project of

```
Project
|
--firstDir
   |
   -- main.py
   -- secondDir
        |
         -- __init__.py
         -- someFuncs.py
```

The **init**.py is empty. SomeFuncs.py provides a function funcOne().
Neither can I

```
from firstDir.secondDir import funcOne
```

out:
no module named 'firstDir'

nor

```
from firstDir.secondDir.someFuncs import funcOne
```

out:
no module named 'firstDir'

nor

```
from .secondDir.someFuncs import funcOne
```

out:
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

The IDE does provide auto completion for all these import approaches.
Whats wrong with these?

Comment: `firstDir` is not a package as it has no `__init__.py`.  Use `from secondDir.someFuncs import funcOne`

Comment: @RoadieRich thanks I'm going to test it tomorrow. But one questions: doesn't the leading dot (from .secondDir.someFuncs import funcOne) indicates a directory-based import? Hence it should work out without making firstDir to a module?

Comment: @RoadieRich, you are right. This works but the IDE was not able to resolve this approach until I had added the directories to the "sources" in the project.